# Image Picker Issue

Tags: iphone, xcode, image, uiimagepickercontroller

We have an issue with the Image Picker in our App. When the camera is launched to take an image, our app restarts and shows the main screen. Can somebody throw some light on this issue?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

I've noticed that the camera needs a lot of memory. When I take a picture the phone sends me memory warnings and view controllers get released. Not a problem in my case, but I guess your app is using too much RAM. You'll have to try to release some when you get memory warnings.

Comment: Thankyou For the reply,we did not have any memory warnings when we use the camera cantroller,actually our app has one controller which handles 5 views ,in 4th view we invoke the imagepicker and use the imagedata in the same view when i came out of the picker the app resumes to the main screen(1st view in the app).

Comment: are you *sure* your didReceiveMemoryWarning function isn't being called?  it really sounds like what you're seeing.